# Track Sitecore Login

Tags: content-editor, login

I need to pull up how many users logged in to Sitecore CM per month (for the past 6 months).  Is there a way I can do this through Sitecore or maybe in core db, which table should I look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it per month then the only way I know is to check the Sitecore logs and search for `AUDIT (<username>): Login` messages. This is only available if you have the logging at `INFO` level.

In the `core` database `aspnet_Membership` table only the `LastLoginDate` is tracked by Sitecore.

If you only have the database as a source you can get some rough numbers through SQL query. For example the following query shows you, how many updates happened per month per one user.

```
SELECT
    Updated_Month = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Updated), 0),
    Value,
    COUNT(Value)
FROM [master_db].[dbo].[VersionedFields]
WHERE FieldId = 'BADD9CF9-53E0-4D0C-BCC0-2D784C282F6A' /* __Updated by field from Sitecore */
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Updated), 0), Value
ORDER BY Updated_Month
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this module https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/S/Sitecore_History_Viewer.aspx to get the list of users that have made some change in CMS.

You can also modify the code to suit your requirement. This may be a very old module but it works for Sitecore 9 as well