# Log-ins and log out in the Sitecore CM instance to Application Insight instance

Tags: identity-server, login, application-insights

**Sitecore version**: `10.1.1 (rev. 005862)`

**What I am trying to do**:
I want to log all log-ins and log out (from the link on the top and cookie expiry) in the Sitecore CM instance to the Application Insight instance.

**What I have found**:
The login and logout (from the link on the top) are being executed through the `Account Controller` in `Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer`.
In the earlier versions of Sitecore, it seems login for individual users was getting logged to the log files ([Link](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24367/track-sitecore-login)). Even this is not happening anymore. I have checked the logs.

Do you have any pointer?

Comment: Does this help https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/33772/how-to-extend-the-existing-login-process you could create custom processor as done in that question and manually push to app inisights

Comment: @DeanOBrien: Thanks for the constructive comment. This approach won't let me log in if a user has provided the wrong password. We intend to log it to identify if there is an attempt for a security breach. The approach in the link doesn't caters to it.